# How to interface PHP and Git repository

Tags: php, git

Recently I was doing a project in which I had to provide a web interface for git repositories 
in my system. I was Coding in PHP and am looking for a way to connect PHP to Git ie, to provide a PHP front end to git.

But can't find any libraries or references to proceed.

Comment: Related: [What's the best Web interface for Git repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438163/whats-the-best-web-interface-for-git-repositories)

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at Git-PHP? http://code.google.com/p/git-php/

There is also:

**glip**

[glip, a git library in PHP](https://github.com/patrikf/glip), enables your PHP scripts to access git repositories. Written in pure PHP5, it works without even having git installed, thus making it the ideal git library to use with your el-cheapo web hosting service.

**GitPHP**

[GitPHP is a web frontend for git repositories](http://www.xiphux.com/programming/gitphp/). It emulates the look of standard gitweb, but is written in PHP and makes use of Smarty templates for customization. It has a couple extras, including syntax highlighting through the GeSHi PHP class and project category support. It works with standard git as well as msysgit on Windows.

Comment: The links from that page seem to be dead.

Comment: Look at the source code on the google project: http://code.google.com/p/git-php/source/browse/trunk/git.php

Answer (score 2):

For those visiting this page in 2021, here is a currently active Git-PHP package (with tests) that you can use to perform common Git operations from PHP.

https://github.com/czproject/git-php

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I got here from Google and maybe this will help others.
I found but did not test yet:

> https://packagist.org/packages/sebastian/git
>
> or
> https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/git